# How to debug yarn / npm in WebStorm

Tags: debugging, npm, webstorm, yarnpkg

Normally I use `yarn` and start my `Node.js` app with `yarn start`. I tried the same in `WebStorm` to debug it, but app does not starts in browser, what is wrong? I can start app, but not debug it.

[image]

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ticket",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.6.1",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.5.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "facebookgraph": "^0.4.0",
    "react": "^16.11.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.11.0",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "3.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "pretty-quick": "^2.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: what does your "start" script look like?

Comment: I added the `Package.json`

Comment: hmm... would you like to debug `react-scripts` module code?

Answer (score 1):

WebStorm reads the package.json by default and places all commands in the left menu

[image]

So if you wanna add more commands just edit the scripts section in your package.json

[image]

You can click for example on start an will be run the script

Comment: I added the `Package.json`, would you look at?

Comment: Downvoted because did not respond the question about "how to debug". Someone new that can "run" the application (as op does) may don't know what script to add to debug, if anything have to be added to the config.
At the end, a newcomer can't debug with this instructions.